# Windsor Configuration Standard Practices

Tags: configuration, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, containers, modularity

The app I inherited uses the fluent interface for configuring our Windsor container, and it's this big glob o' configuration that's pretty disgusting.

In the past I created an extension method container.AddModule and then created modules that were passed in the container and registered services a la StructureMap for the different "modules" of my system that need configuration.

```
container.AddModule(new FooModule());
...
public class FooModule : IWindsorModule
{
  public Register(IWindsorContainer container)
  {
    container.Register(/*Windsor's Ridiculous Fluent Syntax*/);
  }
}
```

Is that what facilities are in Windsor? Are the analogous to StructureMap modules or are they extension points for adding super-magic to Windsor?

What is the best-practice for making your container config more modular and less insane?

Comment: James - Facilities are extensions to the container,adding new capabilities http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Facilities.ashx

What do you find ridiculous about Windsor's syntax? I'd be happy to hear you elaborate on this. Can you hop on to Castle Users group on Google groups? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `IWindsorInstaller`:

- http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx
- http://www.castlecasts.com/Episodes/9/Show/using-windsor

Also if you're coming from StructureMap [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121185834/http://geekswithblogs.net/wesm/archive/2010/02/25/sexy-windsor-registrations.aspx) might be useful.

There's a thin line with Facilities but in general, facilities are intended to be used for more complex stuff that requires custom configuration / several *internal* components, etc.

Comment: How could I have not seen this before? Perfect!